# Flip ViewPager like ViewFlipper

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have implemented ViewPager to swipe between multiple views.

What i want is to flip each of the view in `viewpager` like `Viewflipper`.

Placing viewflipper inside viewpager in xml layout generates random layout.